# update look at table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Good Morning Everyone,

We have test1 and test2 environments. There are 2 tables contact and users table in both environments.

```
T.Contact T.User
T1.User
```

The contact is reference table and have to update user table ID. Now, we are doing following steps to update in user ID of T.Contact:

1. find last name in ID of T.User according to User IDs in T.Contact
2. find IDs in T1.User for updated ID
3. change User IDs in T.Contact

***We are wondering whether better ways are exist or not.***

If we had a same DB, we could use like this: assumptions.

```
UPDATE T.Contact
SET USER_ID IN (
    SELECT USER_ID 
    FROM T.User A, T.Contact B , T1.User C
    WHERE A.LNAME = C.LNAME 
      AND A.FNAME = C.FNAME 
      AND A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
)
```

Is it possible to call different environments DB?

Thanks

Adding Notes:

We should say Different Schemas instead of environments.

Comment: That UPDATE doesn't make sense. `SET USER_ID` must be followed by a `=`.

Comment: Also, if the tables are all on the same instance, then all you need to do is make sure you reference the correct schema in your update statement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [database links](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin002.htm).

You can create a link from one database to another like this:

`CREATE DATABASE LINK otherdb CONNECT TO schema IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'service_name'`;

Then you can use it in queries like this:

```
select ...
from tablename@otherdb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with two separate databases, or just two schemas in the same database?

Comment: Thank Gigatron, just two schemas in the same database. If you have a chance, please share four us.